# Using MinGW in Eclipse for OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, opengl, mingw

I've installed a vanilla version of Eclipse Juno x86_64 on Windows 7, adding some stuff like CDT (for C/C++ OpenGL development).  I have also installed MinGW separately to see if that would solve the problem.

**Problem:** When trying to 
    `#include <GL/gl.h>`
    `#include <GL/glu.h>`
Eclipse tells me that it is an unresolved inclusion (and errors out if I try to build).

Although the Internet seems to agree that these files are in Windows by default, I installed MinGW and they appeared in there (although I've found files like *glu32.a* in the *Microsoft SDK* folder).

I've added MinGW/bin to my PATH and Environment Variable, the selected Tool is *GNU C*, I've added GlU32.Lib and OpenGL32.Lib to the libraries in Paths and Symbols, with/without MinGW, restarting Eclipse, moving files to different locations, etc.

A lot of the articles/tutorials I've found are outdated, don't work for me, and/or not for Windows Eclipse.  I would prefer to use Eclipse over MS Visual Studio and I have been strongly recommended to use Windows rather than Linux.  I'm a beginner in OpenGL and burnt out as of now, so I'm hoping this will help.

Comment: What you seem to be missing is the correct path to where the headers are.

Comment: Don't use glu.h, it is legacy OpenGL. And use a name mangler, like GLEW, that helps you access OpenGL functions. If so, you would include GL/glew.h instead of GL/gl.h. Of course, this is not an answer to your problem, on where to find the header files.

Comment: Uhh, you probably know this, but just to make sure: If you are using #include <.h>, compiler searches the include directory specified by /I option, then it tries to search the current working directory. There is no "It's in Windows by default", there is an enviroment variable called INCLUDE that points the default include directory though (not necessarily on mingw, i'm used to work with vs so you better check if the name is the same). Sorry if this didnt help whatsoever :))